# Plotting log likelihood of bernoulli distribution

Tags: r, coin-flipping

I have a dataset containing the results of 10 fair coin tosses for 5 different students.

The formula that I found for the log likelihood is ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup> log p**X_i(1-p)**1-X_i

How can I plot this in R ? my values are [8,8,4,5,6] and probability is 0.5 (p = 0.5) since it is a fair coin toss.

Comment: hint: `dbinom(..., log=TRUE)`.  Please update your question, with r code, with  showing your efforts and where you have got stuck.

Comment: Actually, your data follow a Binomial distribution (in theory) since each student tossed 10 coins, not 1.

Comment: @Edward so you are saying that i should use the likelihood function for the binomial distribution instad f bernoulli ? even if the order in which the heads/tails happen is not important ?

Comment: Yes. Order is irrelevant for Binomial distribution.